# drillthrough SSRS report error for AssignedTo parameter

Tags: tfs, reporting-services-2012

I have created PieChart which is generating drillthrough report (TFS SSRS) based on parameters. I am passing two parameters, `Microsoft_VSTS_Common_Severity` & `System_AssignedTo`. I have given "**All**" as default to both parameters.

Drilldown report works fine with selected value for `Microsoft_VSTS_Common_Severity` & default (All) for `System_AssignedTo`

but gives an error if I pass any selected value for `System_AssignedTo` parameter.

The error says:

```
An error occurred during local report processing. Query execution failed for dataset 'datasetName'. Parser: The syntax for 'LastName' is incorrect.
```

Any help to resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it's the issue for the column "LastName". Have you done any upgrade or change in the source table. Make sure the Column Name and data type is correct for "LastName" in the source table.